# adding more fields to the comments form including image upload

Tags: comments

I want to be able to add more fields to the comment form including a date field and a multiple image upload field.

I have found a few links showing how it might be possible to add more text fields but how would i allow uploading of multiple photos?

When using this contact form the user will be logged in.
Ideally I would like to upload the image and have it resized as using WordPress uploader but is this possible as it is on the front end?

i do use Gravity Forms but as far as I am aware currently it is not possible to use this with comments?

any help will be greatly appreciated

thanks

Comment: [Answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/10740/12615) with a simple solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can explain to you here how to do it , but it is quite long , it evolves many functions,and a long code (even if simple with the new comments form functions and hooks).
so the best is just get a plugin that will simplify all.
Try [this one .](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-comment-images/) , or search others on the same repository .

**edit** : this might be more suitable for you than :

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/easy-comment-uploads/

Comment: that plugin would be good if it uploaded the image but it only allows you to enter a url of an image already on the web somewhere.

Comment: see my edit in the answer

Comment: Excellent that looks great

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at our extensive new plugin !

It allows for the addition of a wide range of new comment fields (drop down boxes, radios, text fields, image upload fields etc).

http://www.solaceten.info/plugins/wp-extra-comment-fields-v2/