# Comment form not supported the image tags

Tags: comment-form

I used the following code to enable image tags in the comment form. If I input the text with image upload, the image not displayed in the displayed comment.

```
    function my_comment_tags() {
    global $allowedtags;
    $allowedtags = array(
        'img' => array(
           'src' => array(),
           'alt' => array(),
           'title' => array(),
           'height' => array(),
           'width' => array()),
        'strong' => array(),
        'em' => array(),
        'a' => array(
          'href' => array (),
          'title' => array ())
    );
   }


   add_action('comment_post', 'my_comment_tags');
```

But it is not working.  Is there any way to upload image in the comment form?

Comment: Please have look at links may these help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58698/upload-images-with-comment

http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10732/exposing-attachment-uploading-to-the-front-end-delicate/10740#10740

Answer (score 0):

Hi please use below code in your `functions.php` to allow `img` tag in comments. For details please follow link [wp_kses_allowed_html](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_kses_allowed_html/) and for more details please follow [trac link](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/kses.php#L620)

```
add_filter( 'wp_kses_allowed_html', array( $this, 'my_kses_allowed_html_hook' ), 20, 2 );

function my_kses_allowed_html_hook( $tags, $context = null ){
    if ( 'post' == $context && ! isset( $tags['img'] ) ) {
        $tags['img'] = array(
            'src' => 1,
            'height' => 1,
            'width' => 1,
            'alt' => 1,
            'title' => 1
        );
    }

    return $tags;
}
```

Thanks!